# What are the main philosophical differences as well as the main differences in general between Catholicism and Eastern Orthodoxy?

Tags: catholicism, eastern-orthodox, comparative-christianity

Again the titular question says everything that I want to ask. I’ve been able to understand to an extent the main differences between the Catholic and Protestant orientations and gather that Eastern Orthodoxy and Catholicism are more mutually similar than either is to Protestantism.  But how do Catholicism and Eastern Orthodoxy mainly differ?

Comment: **Seeking Answers** Your definition of Protestantism is unbecoming, and your supposition is uncalled for!  Most protestants consider their Faith to be reasonable, biblical, and charitable.  Their differences from Catholicism and Orthodoxy are considered only after scholarly debate and theological research.  This question concerning Cath. and Ortho. could stand  without references to Protestantism, and it is recommended that  therefore the Ques. be edited accordingly.----Keep studying the Bible, it's great for the soul!

Comment: @raygrant Fair enough. Point taken